# MongoDB: Mapreduce: reduce->multiple not supported yet

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection (named "catalog") containing about 5 astronomical catalogs. Several of these catalogs reference each other, so one of the the documents might look something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ec574a68e4e7a519166015f"), "bii" : 20.9519, "class" : 2480, "cpdname" : "CPD -21 6109", "decdeg" : -21.8417, "decpm" : 0.004, "dmname" : "-21 4299", "hdname" : "HD 145612", "lii" : 352.8556, "name" : "PPM 265262", "ppmname" : "PPM 265262", "radeg" : 243.2005, "rapm" : 0.0012, "vmag" : 9.6, "xref" : [ ] }
```

What I want to do is use mapreduce to move the fields such as "hdname","ppmname", etc into the xref array (then unset them).

So I try to do this one at a time, starting with the hdname field. Here are the map and reduce functions:

```
map = function() {
    for (var hdname in this.hdname) {
        emit(this._id,this.hdname);
    }
}


reduce = function(key, values) {
    var result = [];
    for (var hdname in values) {
        result.push(hdname);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I try running the following command in the mongo shell:

```
db.catalog.mapReduce(map, reduce,"catalog2");
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Thu Nov 17 15:52:17 uncaught exception: map reduce failed:{
    "assertion" : "reduce -> multiple not supported yet",
    "assertionCode" : 10075,
    "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Obviously I'm a newbie... can anyone help?

Jason

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The documentation says *"Currently, the return value from a reduce function cannot be an array (it's typically an object or a number)."*

So create an object instead and wrap your array in that.  Make sure also that the output of reduce is the same as the input type, so you'll need to emit a similar value in the map operation.

BUT ... why use Map-Reduce to do this?  If you emit the _id value there's nothing to reduce as each key will be unique.  Why not just iterate over the collection copying the values  and updating each record one by one?

Comment: Understood. I'll still need to mapreduce some duplicates later, but you were correct that I didn't need it here.

Comment: I'm having unusual memory problems with long-running cursor queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185358/why-does-mongodb-client-use-more-memory-than-the-server-in-this-case/

Comment: I wanted to find all IDs that had duplicate policy nos

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169364/rails-mongoid-unique-results, for an example of how to return the object to wrap the array.

Answer (score 2):

I recently needed to return a dictionary as well in my reduce step. Solved this by doing

```
return values.toString();
```

in my reducer code. After that I have to parse the result to get individuals, but that wasn't a big deal...

Answer (score 1):

try to return object in reduce function

```
reduce = function(key, values) {
   var result = [];
   for (var hdname in values) {
     result.push(hdname);
   }
   return {value:result};
}
```