# Why does MongoDB *client* use more memory than the server in this case?

Tags: mongodb

I'm evaluating MongoDB. I have a small 20GB subset of documents. Each is essentially a request log for a social game along with some captured state of the game the user was playing at that moment.

I thought I'd try finding game cheaters. So I wrote a function that runs server side. It calls find() on an indexed collection and sorts according to the existing index. Using a cursor it goes through all documents in indexed order. The index is {user_id,time}. So I'm going through each user's history, checking if certain values (money/health/etc) increase faster than is possible in the game. The script returns the first violation found. It does not collect violations.

The ONLY thing that this script does on the client is define the function and calls `mymongodb.eval(myscript)` on a mongod instance on another box.

The box that mongod is running on does fine. The one that the script is launched from starts losing memory and swap. Hours later: 8GB of RAM and 6GB of swap are being used on the client machine that did nothing more than launch a script on another box and wait for a return value.

Is the mongo client really that flakey? Have I done something wrong or made an incorrect assumption about mongo/mongod?

Comment: As a matter of principle Mongo pushes as much work as possible to the client. This does seem like an extreme case though - although from what you describe a map/reduce might be more suited to getting similar data?

Comment: Not sure why it would push anything to the client in this case. Especially since I'm calling `eval`. It seems very strange to me.

Comment: Not sure either but either way you don't seem to be using Mongo the way it is intended to be used (at least as I understand it) which doesn't make it a very fair evaluation! I'd suggest not using eval and simply doing the work on the client. That's how it's designed to be used. Either that or a map/reduce to find all cheaters and then query that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to open up a client connection to a remote database you should use the `mongo` command, not `mongod`. `mongod` starts up a server on your local machine. Not sure what specifying a url will do.

Try

```
mongo remotehost:27017
```

Comment: Yes I am running only mongo on my local machine and mongod on the server.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution):

> Use map/reduce instead of db.eval() for long running jobs. db.eval blocks other operations!

`eval` is a function that blocks the entire server if you don't use a special flag. Again, from the docs:

> If you don't use the "nolock" flag, db.eval() blocks the entire mongod process while running [...]

You are kind of abusing MongoDB here. Your current routine is strange, because it returns the first violation found, but it will have to re-check everything when run the next time (unless your user ids are ordered and you store the last evaluated user id).

Map/Reduce generally is the better option for a long-running task, but aggregating your data does not seem trivial. However, a map/reduce based solution would also solve the re-evaluation problem.

I'd probably return something like this from map/reduce:

```
user id -> suspicious actions, e.g.
------
2525454 -> [{logId: 235345435, t: ISODate("...")}]
```

Comment: I can simply restart the query at the index of the found violation and continue from there. It's not clear to me how I'm abusing mongo. I am using the built in cursor function as intended. I don't need to run anything else at the same time so I don't care about locking. The code should be running on the server but the client is having it's memory eaten.

Comment: In general, the indexes would not be stable. It works for you only because you are not inserting in the mean time. That seems to make sense for a simple test, but is rather unusual for a live system. Anyway, you're abusing it because you are performing a long-running operation using `db.eval`, but the documentation explicitly says you shouldn't, setting aside the blocking which presumably is only one of the consequences to be aware of. Map/reduce is the right tool for this job I'd say.

Comment: It seems the caveat in the long running eval is that it locks. I understand. Nowhere can I find a reason that it should consume all my client side memory. By saying that I shouldn't use something for a side effect I don't (currently) care about, we are dismissing the effect I am concerned and curious about. Even if I switch to a map-reduce solution, I'd like to understand this current problem.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't use because of some side effect. I'm saying you shouldn't use it because the docs *explicitly say so*. As for the client behavior, that seems to be some arcane detail of a specific (and less relevant) client. Why would you use the js shell, other than for administrative purposes? If you want to find out what is going on exactly, you can dive into the source code, but I don't see where this helps you in evaluating MongoDB?

Comment: Mongo ships with the shell. I can write queries and map/reduce jobs and execute them in the shell. Why wouldn't I use it? The documentation you quote seems to be saying use map/reduce if you want to avoid blocking. The documentation also says "Queries to MongoDB return a cursor, which can be iterated to retrieve results." So I CAN use a curser to iterate the results.

Comment: This answer seems to advise against map-reduce when it doesn't make sense: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175015/mongodb-mapreduce-reduce-multiple-not-supported-yet/8177572#8177572

Comment: It seems you already have an opinion on how to read the documentation, and you seem to know better when map/reduce makes sense. If you know the answer, why do you ask a question in the first place?