# Get documents with unique field - Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `ratings` collection with the field `item_id`. I need to retrieve all documents with different `item_id` field. For instance, let's suppose I have this documents:

```
{item_id: "123", some_other_field: "bla,bla"}
{item_id: "123", some_other_field: "bla,bla"}
{item_id: "121", some_other_field: "bla,bla"}
{item_id: "120", some_other_field: "bla,bla"}
```

The result that I need:

```
{item_id: "123", some_other_field: "bla,bla"}
{item_id: "121", some_other_field: "bla,bla"}
{item_id: "120", some_other_field: "bla,bla"}
```

How can I achieve this? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169364/rails-mongoid-unique-results) question where they propose map-reduce as the solution, but it should be something easier!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite a lot easier if what you "mean" here is the "completely distinct" document. But what you basically need here is [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/), and specifically [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
Model.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group" => {
        "_id" => {
            "item_id" => "$item_id",
            "some_other_field" => "$some_other_field"
        }
    }}
])
```

Or if you just want "distinct" on "one" field, then something like:

```
Model.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group" => {
        "_id" => "$item_id",
        "some_other_field" => { "$first" => "$some_other_field" }
    }}
])
```

These are no longer the mongoid "documents" but you can always "cast" them back if the structure is the same, and that is possible with a little manipulation or the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) pipeline stage.

```
Model.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group" => {
        "_id" => "$item_id",
        "some_other_field" => { "$first" => "$some_other_field" }
    }},
    { "$project" => {
        "_id" => 0,
        "item_id" => "$_id",
        "some_other_field" => "$some_other_field"
    }}
])
```

Also to mention that this is "significantly" faster than mapReduce, as the code uses native operators to MongoDB and no JavaScript translation.

Read up on the [operators for aggregation pipelines](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) as a general guide to things you can do.