# How to group date quarterly wise?

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have documents which contain a date and I'm wondering how to group them according to quarterly basis?

My schema is:

```
var ekgsanswermodel = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    topicId : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    ekgId : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    answerSubmitted :{type: Number},
    dateAttempted : { type: Date},
    title : {type: String},
    submissionSessionId : {type: String}  
});
```

1st quarter contains months 1, 2, 3. 2nd quarter contains months 4, 5, 6 and so on up-to 4th quarter.

My final result should be:

```
 "result" : [ 
   {
     _id: {
        quater:
     },
     _id: {
        quater:
     },
    _id: {
        quater:
     },
     _id: {
        quater:
     }
  }
```

Comment: have you tried using MongoDB's mapreduce?
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

I think you can map your months by rounded MonthNumber/4. Something like emit(this.number/4, this.number). And in REDUCE part, you group all the months.

Comment: I have not tried mapreduce. can give me a example. i added schema also above.

Comment: Nevermind my solution @grishabh, the one below is better. Mongodb mapreduce does not allow you to have an array as a result of reduce operation.

Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175015/mongodb-mapreduce-reduce-multiple-not-supported-yet

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could make use of the [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator to check if:

- The [`$month`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) is `<= 3`, project a field named `quarter` with
  value as "one".
- The `$month` is `<= 6`, project a field named `quarter` with
  value as "two".
- The `$month` is `<= 9`, project a field named `quarter` with
  value as "three".
- else the value of the field `quarter` would be "fourth".
- Then `$group` by the `quarter` field.

Code:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      date: 1,
      quarter: {
        $cond: [
          { $lte: [{ $month: "$date" }, 3] },
          "first",
          {
            $cond: [
              { $lte: [{ $month: "$date" }, 6] },
              "second",
              {
                $cond: [{ $lte: [{ $month: "$date" }, 9] }, "third", "fourth"],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  { $group: { _id: { quarter: "$quarter" }, results: { $push: "$date" } } },
]);
```

Specific to your schema:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      dateAttempted: 1,
      userId: 1,
      topicId: 1,
      ekgId: 1,
      title: 1,
      quarter: {
        $cond: [
          { $lte: [{ $month: "$dateAttempted" }, 3] },
          "first",
          {
            $cond: [
              { $lte: [{ $month: "$dateAttempted" }, 6] },
              "second",
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $lte: [{ $month: "$dateAttempted" }, 9] },
                  "third",
                  "fourth",
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  { $group: { _id: { quarter: "$quarter" }, results: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
]);
```

Comment: thanx @BatScream, Please can you make this query in spring-data-mongodb.

Answer (score 5):

You could use following to group documents quarterly.

```
{
    $project : {
        dateAttempted : 1,
        dateQuarter: {
            $trunc : {$add: [{$divide: [{$subtract: [{$month: 
            "$dateAttempted"}, 1]}, 3]}, 1]}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting in `Mongo 5`, it's a perfect use case for the new [`$dateTrunc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/) aggregation operator:

```
// { date: ISODate("2012-10-11") }
// { date: ISODate("2013-02-27") }
// { date: ISODate("2013-01-12") }
// { date: ISODate("2013-03-11") }
// { date: ISODate("2013-07-14") }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$date", unit: "quarter" } },
    total: { $count: {} }
  }}
])
// { _id: ISODate("2012-10-01"), total: 1 }
// { _id: ISODate("2013-01-01"), total: 3 }
// { _id: ISODate("2013-07-01"), total: 1 }
```

[`$dateTrunc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/) truncates your dates at the beginning of their `quarter` (the truncation `unit`). It's kind of a modulo on dates per quarter.

Quarters in the output will be defined by their first day (`Q3 2013` will be `2013-07-01`). And you can always adapt it using [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) projection for instance.